# powerapps create accordion section for different fields of the same list

Tags: modern-experience, powerapp

we currently have a requirement from a client to create powerapps form in accordion fashion with fields for section to be collapse/expandable

is there any such sample implementation available so that it could be very helpful for us

Comment: take a look at this - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/accordions-ui-in-powerapps/ if it helps

Comment: You can achieve it using nested gallery and a parent child backend list. But limited to known sub levels.